# Composer does not respect installer-paths

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is the scenario:

I have two projects driven by composer. The first one looks like this:

```
{
"name": "myusername/composer_test",
"description": "Composer project for CircleK Drupal 8",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Name Surname",
        "role": "webdeveloper"
    }
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
    "drupal/core": "^8.7.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"]
    }
}
}
```

Second one requires the first one and it's pretty straight forward:

```
{
  "name": "user/site",
  "description": "Composer for Site",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Name Surname",
      "role": "webdeveloper"
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:myusername/composer_test.git"
    },
    {
          "type": "composer",
          "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
      "myusername/composer_test": "dev-drupal_only"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

As you can see the first one defines where drupal core should be placed at by defining `installer-paths`. It turns out that when I run composer install just for the first composer.json file drupal core ends up in `./web` directory as should, however when I run composer install for second file it does download every package from first composer.json just fine, but drupal core ends up in main directory instead of `./web`. I know I can put `installer-paths` into the last composer file and overwrite it, but that's not the point. I want first file to define where stuff should be place at.

Comment: A lot of composers settings only work for the root package while it ignores those settings when a composer file is loaded as a dependency. I don't know if this is one of them though. It might be worth looking into?

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, that's what I suspected, but couldn't find any confirmation in composer manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra settings only work for the root package. Consider `user/site` requiring 2 different packages that both specifiy different installer paths. Which one should composer use and how should it know? By ignoring those settings, unless they are specified in your root composer.json, composer circumvents any surprises/problems.

There is a way around this, you can create a post-install script that determines the correct path for you, e.g. by checking if `myusername/composer_test` is installed and the variable is set. This is a bit similar to how Symfony's Install-Script in the [SensioDistributionBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L433) used to do it. It provides a fallback to determine the right directory to use based on configs and folder structure (due to changes in how the default directory structure looks at ~2.8, e.g. moving app/console to bin/console).

You could write your own install script that inspects the installed composer packages. The downside is, that just like you now have to specify the extra config in your second composer.json, you will have to specify the install scripts, plus you have to write the install script itself. So it might be a lot of extra work without gaining a lot from it.

Comment: Right, I was thinking about setting up composer hook that runs after install and moves files to it's destinated paths, but if that's the case I guess I'm going to do it a bit differently. I suppose your solution would work, but it bring more complexity rather then simplicity and automation. Of course this can be applied in some cases, but it doesn't apply to my project's needs. Thanks for clarification.